# How to use bolt/italic fonts in a Vim colorscheme?

Tags: vim

I've been making a custom colorscheme for myself, but I can't seem to figure out how to apply bold/italic font to my code syntax.

I've got a series of lines like `let s:keyword=#0197F4` to define colors to variables, then more lines below like `exe 'hi Keyword guifg='s:keyword'  gui=bold'` to assign colors and text decoration. This is from a template I found, not my original code. I've got `set termguicolors` in my .vimrc as well.

However, the `gui=bold` part doesn't actually seem to do anything. I'm using Vim in the terminal (iTerm2) and I know it's capable of bold text, because when I load up my .vimrc, I can see that it *does* work. For example, the phrase `g:python_highlight_all` is bold.

I'm using python code snippets to test my highlighting, if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

- `gui`, `guibg`, and `guifg` are attributes specific to **GUI** Vim,
- `cterm`, `ctermbg`, and `ctermfg` are attributes specific to **c**olor **term**inals.

You say:

> the `gui=bold` part doesn't actually seem to do anything

and then:

> I'm using Vim in the terminal

Since you are running Vim in a terminal emulator, the right attribute is rather obviously `cterm`, not `gui`.

Comment: I realized that seems silly, but assigning colors using ``guifg`` and ``guibg`` is working normally. I tested your answer by applying ``cterm=italic`` to my comment highlighting, and it... reversed the text? Rather than being dark gray text, they're now black text on a dark gray background. I'm more confused now than I was before.

Comment: I've now found that underline and bold both work using ``cterm``, but italic inverts the colors like I explained above.

Comment: 1. `guifg` and `guibg` "work" because you have `set termguicolors`. That's the whole point of that option: `:help 'termguicolors'`. 2. Vim's internal logic for determining if the host terminal supports italic has been flawed for decades.

Comment: Thanks, that's all I need to know.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same confusion, and then I found that vim's `termguicolor` was designed to only use gui colors instead of gui font attributes. You can try my workaround script or this [plug-in](https://github.com/rwxe/termguiattrhook) I wrote.

```
command SetTermGuiAttr call TermGuiAttrHook() 
"Override cterm attributes with gui attributes
function! TermGuiAttrHook()
    for group in getcompletion('', 'highlight')
        let group_config = execute('hi ' . group)
        let gui_match = matchlist(group_config, 'gui\s*=\s*\zs\S\+\ze')
        let gui_values = filter(gui_match, 'v:val != ""')
        if !empty(gui_values)
            let gui_value = gui_values[0]
            execute 'hi ' . group . ' cterm=' . gui_value
        endif
    endfor
endfunction
```